# Get list of Spaces where the Google hangout chat bot is installed?

Tags: google-hangouts

https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces/list

I am using this to get a list of all spaces where the bot is installed, but am not able to get a response:

Here is the code snippet.

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'service-account.json', scopes)
http = Http()
credentials.authorize(http)
chat = build('chat', 'v1', http=http) 
res = chat.spaces().list()
print res.body.   ----- this gives null
```

am I missing something here ?

Comment: But you define the right scopes, implement `from apiclient.discovery import build` and give to the service account the necessary scopes in the admin console? Also: Are you member of the chatrooms you are looking for?

Comment: i am having the same issue, any idea how to get this working? i am able to send to the space, but when calling the list method it returns empty

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing this issue,

Use `res = chat.spaces().list().execute()` 
instead of `res = chat.spaces().list()`